# What is the difference between assignment, valuation and name binding?

Tags: terminology, programming-languages, variable-binding

I read that [Name binding assigns some value (data/code/expression) to an identifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_binding). [Assignment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_(computer_science)) and [valuation](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/16098) seem to do the same thing. It is confusing. Can I just tell that free variable is one, which was not assigned a value whereas bound variable has its value assigned?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Binding has to do with giving names to things (or values) in a given well delimited context. Assignment is about storing things (or values) in some location (a variable). Another assignment can replace a previous value with a new one. Valuation consist in binding all the identifiers of a formal text with something (with a value).  In mathematics these identifiers are often called variables, which causes a confusion with the concept of variable (i.e. memory storage) in computer science.

### Trying to give more intuitive details

Name binding attaches a meaning to identifiers within some part
(called scope) of the concerned mathematical or programming text.
This meaning can indeed be seen as a value in some domain when the
text is interpreted.

For example, if you declare `foo` as an integer variable, the value
attached to `foo` within the scope is an integer variable. An integer
variable may be seen informally a a container that can carry an
integer value, which may be changed. You can also see it as the address of a
place in memory where the content may be stored.

But if you declare `foo` as the integer 25, then whithin the scope,
any use of `foo` is identical to a use of 25. If you declare foo as an
integer constant, it cannot change and thus its value must be
specified.

Binding is attaching a name to some value that does not change within the scope of the name. An example is a legal documents stating that "`for the purpose of this document, Mr. Brown, and the Smith family shall be called the beneficiary.`" The scope is the legal document. And everywhere in the document, the use of the word `beneficiary` means Mr. Brown, and the Smith family. You can see it as a definition of a local terminology. It has to do with giving names to things. Binding is about speaking, reading or writing. It is not about executing or moving values around: that corresponds to assignment.

A variable may be seen as a chunk of memory that can contain a value,
When you have a variable, you can change the value contained in this variable
contains with an assignment. If `foo` is bound to (or denotes) a variable in
the current scope, you can assign a value to `foo`, i.e. to the
variable denoted by `foo`, or read the value contained in that
variable. And you can change that value with a new assignment.

So binding is an operation that tells what is the meaning of names in
the text of the program or of the mathematical discourse. It is
static, in the sense that the text does not change. But
assignment is a programming concept that consist is storing a value in
a variable, i.e. a container, which is usually a place in memory. It
is a dynamic concept related to how (representations of) values are
stored in memory, which changes as the program progresses.

Note that a variable may exist independently of any name to which it could be bound. This is the case for an element of an array, to take a simple example.

In various contexts, one may consider expressions or texts that use
names that have not been defined. For example you can write
$(a^2-b^2)/(a-b)$ which is an arithmetic expression. Then you may
valuate the variables by associating an environment (you may read
approximately a scope) where the variables $a$ and $b$ are bound to some
values, for example 3 and 12, and be interested in the value taken by
the exression.  A valuation is such an association of a set of names,
each with a specific value. The name valuation is used more in formal mathematics, while assigment is a programming concept.

Comment: To summarize, you basically confirm that all operations assign a value to variable/identifier/placeholder. The difference is the context. When we map guest (program) to host (machine), we say `binding`. When variable is bound to some value during program execution, we say `it was assigned` and we prefer to say `valuated` in the formal/cs context instead. I just started to look at the free/bound variables today and confused. It is like formal/cs context, yet, compiler/computer engeneer jargon is used?

Comment: @RecognizeEvilasWaste I have attempted to clarify. But there is a difficulty due to the fact that mathematical terminology conflicts with computer science terminology. A variable cannot be bound to some value, a variable is assigned a value. An identifier is bound to a meaning, but the formal notion of meaning is some value in a semantics domain. You do not assign identifiers, you do not bind variables. Identifiers are syntax, speech. Variables are memory, used to store information. Actually, it is computer jargon that was derived from the formal speech.

Comment: Your confusion is understandable. In lambda calculus, the word
variable is used for what I call identifier.  More generally, there is
a whole branch of programming, called functional programming, that is
not supposed to use assignment. So, in principle everything is done
through binding, but it gives a very different style of programming.
Lambda calculus is the basic formal example of that. However, they
still talk of variables for what is identifiers. You question is fair, and the terminology is
messy. Well I did my best.

Comment: @RecognizeEvilasWaste Your question is actually a very good one. I had not realized how much ambiguity this creates for beginners.

Comment: Not only for novice. I would say that I am quite experienced in these issues. I can understand what they mean. But I always have difficulty which term to use when I want to say similar things. I also like to see the relationships between things, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User:Javalenok This helps understanding.

Comment: Also, I remember a textbook saying that free variables are evaluated by environments, the variable name -> value mappings, which additionally identifies variables with identifiers and thereby says that free variables are bound, that binding is the same as assignment. This cannot be not confusing.